Unable to build for IOS
Thank you for your help. We're currently in the process of deploying to production, but I'm having trouble generating the iOS version. When I try to build the iOS version, I encounter an error. :
com_codename1_googlemaps_InternalNativeMapsImpl.h:19:9: fatal error: 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h' file not found
#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>
my configuration in codename one seting :
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,GoogleMaps,Google-Maps-iOS-Utils,
com_codename1_googlemaps_InternalNativeMapsImpl.h:19:9: fatal error: 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h' file not found
#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>
my configuration in codename one seting :
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,GoogleMaps,Google-Maps-iOS-Utils,

I'll need the full error log. Also make sure you're using the latest version of the cn1lib. You can post the log in a github gist and provide the link to it here.

below the link :
https://gist.github.com/soufianemaadour/76114634d8dcd1ef0a1c4e0c79188f6f

In the sample code for the marker clustering they use @import GoogleMapsUtils; in Objective-C and not #import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>. I suggest trying that.
